# Smart UV project creates overlapping uv-coordinates

Tags: texturing, uv

I am having a UV-Sphere with 23k vertices and 25k faces. I used the Smart UV project to create UV-Coordinates but I was surpries to see that some of the faces are overlapping.

[image]

I was able to reproduce that behaviour with a simple plane, which I subdivided two times and then moved two vertices. The Smart UV Project's angle limit must be 89.00.

[image]

Is that a bug? I thought every face should have it's own uv-coordinates as well as texture space.

FYI: The first picture was done with Smart UV project Angle Limit 66.00.

**UPDATE**

This also happens when I use a Smart UV project on a uvsphere where the vertices are moved along their normal with a value out of a noise function.
[image]
This can't be right?

Comment: Maybe this paper could help for finding better seams: (Vallet Bruno, L´evy Bruno, What you seam is what you get: automatic and interactive UV unwrapping
, http://alice.loria.fr/publications/papers/2009/wysiwyg_tr/wysiwyg.pdf) Just for the record, maybe a blender developer finds that.

Comment: Blender Bug Report: https://developer.blender.org/T45520

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Smart UV Project simply doesn't guarantee non-overlapping UVs.

It doesn't detect or correct self-intersecting UV's within a UV-island.

Using lower angle limit will typically help to avoid this problem, but there are still cases it could happen.

If the possibility of overlapping UV's is unacceptable, you could use **Lightmap-pack** instead.

---

Note, in the example given - there is a lot of *noise*, One way to resolve could mitigate overlapping could be calculate the UV's on a less noisy version of the mesh:

- Store the original vertex locations.
- Smooth the vertices.
- Execute Smart-Project
- Restore the vertex locations.

Comment: If I use Lightmap-pack than there aren't any texture-islands. That means that when I decimate the mesh (for level of detail) the uv's aren't merged. What do you mean with "there is a lot of noise"? The vertices are manipulated via noise, thats on purpose. The Updated-Example shows a UV-Sphere where the vertices are manipulated, too. But not that much and still happens. Is there a way Smart UV Project could be improved so that something like that isn't happening?

Comment: Even though the *noise* is on purpose, its making some UV tools give worse results (that try to make the texture coordinates follow the surface). Thats why I suggest smoothing the vertices temporarily to calculate UV's

Answer (score 1):

### Because there are [non-planar/concave quads](http://strattonbrazil.blogspot.it/2009/12/ngons-are-they-really-that-evil.html).

Unfortunately I don't know the math behind the algorithm itself, but I can guess that this kind of faces are not easy to handle for this kind of operation.

Blender has to do calculation about the angle between faces. If that angle overcome a thershold (the angle limit) the edge between faces become a point of discontinuity, a seam.

If the face has an ambiguous geometry, it becames more difficult to have a predictable behavior, as what the modeler sees may not be what the software understand.

[image]

The image above shows two possible triangulation of a non-planar quad face. If the modeler doesn't specify which one is the expected geometry, the software could not act as expected.

A predictable behavior can be achieve by solving ambiguities. One (brutal) way is to triangulate (not only the overlapping-uv faces, but a bigger area as adjacent faces are also take in account in the calculation).

Notice in the images below how a triangulate mesh is not affected by overlapping uv.

[image] [image]

...and in your example:

[image] [image]

It may not enter in the UV-unwrapping hall of fame,... but at least there isn't any overlap.

Comment: Did you triangulate with the triangulate-modifier? Could you upload the screenshots in a higher resolution? And how do you know that a triangulated mesh is not affected by overlapping uvs? In your screenshot the texture space is overlapping, isn't it?

Comment: No, i triangulated with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>T</kbd>. Sorry, I thought they were bigger...And you are right..there are still some small overlaps! I'll check this fact and extend the answer as soon as possible

Comment: You are right! In corrispondence with great angle differences tris are stitt not able to avoid overlapping http://it.tinypic.com/r/9u4qwj/8. Currently I can't give you a proper answer...I hope somebody will

Comment: Thank you for your help! Maybe that's a bug in the implementation of the algorithm which hasn't attracted someones attention because normally you don't have that extreme spikes in a mesh.